# I want to change the color of a button for a few seconds than change it back

Tags: android, android-layout, button

My Android button color is blue. I want to change the button color to red for 5 seconds. After 5 seconds, I need to change the button color back to blue.

Here is my code

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    eyesOnchkBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }, 5000);


            eyesOnchkBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); // It wont change the color button as normal
```

Comment: new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    eyesOnchkBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
            }, 5000);


            eyesOnchkBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

Comment: Inside Handler Give Blue and outside RED

Comment: The code in your question would - if it would work correctly - set the color of the button to blue immediately and after 5 secs to red. What I understand from your text, it should be vice versa.

Comment: yes. your right.. My Android button color is blue. when i click the button it will change to red color and after 5 seconds it will change to back normal blue color.

Comment: @jboi Yes, you are right. Actually she wants something else and doing something else.

Comment: @Seetha if you color is blue, change it to red in onClick and in the handler change it back to blue !

Comment: Now i got the answer. Thanks for your all help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope the following code will help

```
eyesOnchkBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
new CountDownTimer(5000, 50) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
                        eyesOnchkBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change your code a bit,

```
 eyesOnchkBtn.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){

 @Override
 public void onClick() {
 // set the color red first.
 eyesOnchkBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

 // change to original after 5 secs.
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    eyesOnchkBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
            }, 5000);
 }
});
```

Comment: you could setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE) before setting the listener, so that she can understand easily. Otherwise its perfect..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Timer myTimer;

MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(myTask, 0, 3000);

class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        public void run() {
            try {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                    //Your color change code here
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

//Stop the timer when you finish your job.

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            myTimer.cancel();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            myTimer.cancel();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I try to implement your code But My Android button color is blue. when i click the button it will change to red color and after 5 seconds it will change to back normal blue color. So where i have to place the code. Thanks

Comment: that's too much a timer for work which can be done by handler .. :\

Comment: when you click on blue button, change the color to red and do Timer start and after 5 seconds of Timer running, make it again blue.

Answer (score 1):

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
button.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
  }
}, 5000);
```